# Unable to run index migration in OpenSearch

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose, opensearch

I have a docker compose running where a django backend, opensearch & opensearch dashboard are running. I have connected the backend to talk to opensearch and I'm able to query it successfully. I'm trying to create indexes using this command inside the docker container.

```
./manage.py opensearch --rebuild
```

Reference: https://django-opensearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/#create-and-populate-opensearchs-indices

I get the following error when I run the above command

```
root@ed186e462ca3:/app# ./manage.py opensearch --rebuild
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py:8: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release.
  from cryptography import utils, x509
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 37, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_opensearch_dsl/management/commands/opensearch.py", line 32, in __init__
    if settings.TESTING:  # pragma: no cover
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 80, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'TESTING'
Sentry is attempting to send 1 pending error messages
Waiting up to 2 seconds
Press Ctrl-C to quit
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help would be greatful.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this was indeed a bug in `django-opensearch-dsl` which was fix in the `0.3.0` release.